# Bootstrap 3.2 Resizing causes popover placement issue using input field and form

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Fee fiddle below.  Put the focus in the input field and resize your browser wid.  The popover will be misplaced when the container div is re-sized.

http://jsfiddle.net/024pvz9d/

```
   <div class="container">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading">Labor Start</div>
         <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-sm-3 control-label" for="employee_number">Employee Number:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 input-group">
                     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fieldModePopover" href="#" data-html="true"
                     data-content="word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word word"
                     rel="popover" data-placement="right"
                     data-original-title="Title">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

I would like the popover to remain on the right side of the input field.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known "bug" of boostrap, since the popovers were not really build for this case. You can try a simple hack like this.

Just add the following code to your JS:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    if ($(".popover").is(":visible"))
    {
        var popover = $(".popover");
        popover.addClass("noTransition");
        $("input:focus").popover('show');
        popover.removeClass("noTransition");
    }
});
```

And this class to your css:

```
.noTransition {
    -moz-transition: none !important;
    -webkit-transition: none !important;
    -o-transition: none !important;
    transition: none !important;
}
```

**[Working Example](http://www.bootply.com/RO6nyT4Lc1)**